# paper.js, SVG and Opera browser

Tags: svg, opera, paperjs

While using SVG images in paperjs found paperjs's `importSvg()` fails under Opera with strange error.

So I made a workaround. Import SVG in other browser first and then export paperjs object's to JSON. Convert my few SVG's to JSON by hands. And now just importing them by `importJson()` and have no worries....

But! `importJson()` is implemented only in nightly build of paperjs, which as I figured out later, with some functions fails under Opera!!

So... I dunno ))) Any ideas?

May be someone of Opera or paperjs crew will come around here someday...

Comment: Just tried, it is possible to take data from the JSON and insert it into the code for creating paperjs’s graphical entities in natural way... though it is not so great…
It seems very possible to automate the ‘SVS’ -> ‘paperscript functions’ conversion. But let’s be looking forward for the best...

Comment: First I'd suggest you to post your example online, eg. on jsfiddle.net. Second, include the error message(s) you get in the question.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle with v0.8 paperjs (latest i found), which fails under Opera 12 (but not under FF, eg): http://jsfiddle.net/dUPbX/3/

Comment: And here is with v0.3 paperjs i just found, which runs! http://jsfiddle.net/dUPbX/4/ But unfortunately has no `importJson()`

Answer (score 1):

The line in paper.js that Opera has a problem with:

```
'stop-color': function(item, value) {
    item.setColor(value);
},
```

If the `item.setColor` line is commented out your example works as it should.